# javascript: how do I set the width of an image after it loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm using facebox to display images neatly, and I wrote a function to help with handeling the size of really big images: (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LPF85/)

```
function open_img_in_face_box(id, width){
    max_width = $j(document).width();
    max_height = $j(document).height();
    padding = 50;

    max_width = max_width - (2 * padding);
    max_height = max_height - (2 * padding);

    passed_width = width || max_width;

    var img = $j('#' + id); 
    dom_img = document.getElementById(id); 

    // display 
    jQuery.facebox({ image: img.attr('src') });

    // center and adjust size
    var aspect_ratio = img.width() / img.height();
    var img_width = passed_width;
    var img_height = passed_width / aspect_ratio;

    window_center_y = max_height / 2;
    window_center_x = max_width / 2;

    offset_y = window_center_y - (img_height / 2);
    offset_x = window_center_x - (img_width / 2);

    var fbx = $j('#facebox');
    fbx.css('left', offset_x + 'px !important');
    fbx.css('top', offset_y + 'px !important')

    $j("#facebox .image img").load(function(){
        $j(this).width(img_width);
    });
}
```

but the problem is that the image remains full size, and never gets changed to 500 (the current value I'm using for img_width).

How do I change the width of the image after it loads, but quickly enough so no one notices?

I've tested this in Chrome, and Safari with this html:

```
<img id="facebox_img" onclick="open_img_in_face_box('facebox_img', 500)" src="/medias/50/original.jpg" width="300" />
```

Comment: At what point is this function called?  And have you tested in multiple browsers?  You may be running into the browser inconsistency of `load`.

Comment: I'll update my question.

Comment: I don't know if the image is in memory at the time of running that code. =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

Replace:

```
$j("#facebox .image img").load(function(){
    $j(this).width(img_width);
});
```

with:

```
 $j(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { 
    $j("#facebox .image img").width(width);
 })
```

This new code listens to the reveal event and sets the width accordingly once all the elements are in place.

Comment: correct. the image and maybe the facebox hasn't loaded yet so that doesn't work at runtime. http://jsfiddle.net/LPF85/ <-- code.  But entering that in tho console after the image loads works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$j("#facebox .image img").each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
        $j(this).width(img_width);
    }).attr("src", $j(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: the width didn't change still. I think it's because the selector doesn't return anything, because the image hasn't loaded yet. or the facebox hasn't finished rendering or something.

Comment: Yes the selector returns no elements.

Comment: I have added some delay before we execute this code it works fine now. Take a look at this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LPF85/2/)

Comment: just checked at your link. The width doesn't appear to be getting set to 500 =\ at least visually.

Comment: When we replace the src with the same src the load event is not triggerd. I have added a dummystring to the src just to change the url and it triggers the load event. Please try it here now [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LPF85/3/). Hope this helped you thanks.

Comment: @TheLindyHop - Did you checked my modified fiddle?